# Is it possible to serialise a Realm Object into JSON?

Tags: ios, json, swift, realm

Does anyone know if there's any support in Realm (iOS) to be able to serialise an `RLMObject` into JSON for export?

Comment: There is a 3rd-party library which allows you to convert all subclasses of `NSObject` into `NSDictionary`, then you can convert resulting object into JSON: https://github.com/aperechnev/APObjectMapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any support officially, but this article may describe some other third party libraries which may be able to achieve what you are after

http://blog.matthewcheok.com/working-with-realm/

Answer (score 0):

It should work like with any other objects:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:realmObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&writeError];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following
>   properties:
>
> The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
>
> - All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html]