# Convert NSObject to RLMObject

Tags: objective-c, model, realm, nsdictionary, nsobject

There is a custom way to get data from Realm model and assign it to NSObject by converting it to NSDictionary first and to NSObject model object second.

But how is that possible to convert it back to set the data back to Realm model from the NSObjects?

May be converting from NSObject to NSDictionary/JSON then back to RLMObject should be suitable?

Comment: this link might be help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940658/is-it-possible-to-serialise-a-realm-object-into-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to serialise a Realm Object into JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940658/is-it-possible-to-serialise-a-realm-object-into-json)

Comment: Thanks, Austin, i will check it out.